# ReactJS - "react-google-maps": after clicking on a marker, no InfoWindow is displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing Google Maps with `react-google-maps` and I am able to render a marker on the map. However, after clicking on the marker, the `InfoWindow` is not displayed. This is my approach:

```
import React from "react";
import { withScriptjs, 
        withGoogleMap, 
        GoogleMap, 
        Marker,
        InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps";

const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
  >
    <Marker 
        position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} 
        onClick={this.onToggleOpen}
    >
        { props.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.onToggleOpen}>asg</InfoWindow>}
    </Marker>
  </GoogleMap>
))
export default class GoogleMapsSample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          isOpen: false
        }
    }

    onToggleOpen(){
        console.log('x');
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
            <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
                <MyMapComponent 
                    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyDFD30jUKH0Cl8qrZoNCe-eEGQBIfApzE0"
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have also tried to look if the `onToggleOpen` action actually triggers when is clicked, but it doesn't - the line `console.log('x');` doesn't execute anything.

It looks that I am probably passing the props incorrectly, however, after trying a few approaches, I still cannot find the right one.

Answer (score 1):

`onToggleOpen` function is defined in parent compoent, So you should pass it and access it as `props.onToggleOpen` in your `MyMapComponent`

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thank you for your reply. In the `render` function, I have set this props: `onToggleOpen={this.onToggleOpen}` to the `MyMapComponent` and inside the `Marker`, I put this: `{props.onToggleOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.onToggleOpen}>asg</InfoWindow>}`, but it results into this error: `Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.` Am I overlooking something? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you are doing wrong and some missing props.
The below should work for you

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";

const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
      <Marker
        position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
        onClick={() => props.onToggleOpen()}
      >
        {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow><div>hey, some info here</div></InfoWindow>}
      </Marker>
    </GoogleMap>
  ))
);

class GoogleMapsSample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
  }

  onToggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen })
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state
    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <MyMapComponent
          googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyDFD30jUKH0Cl8qrZoNCe-eEGQBIfApzE0"
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          isOpen={isOpen}
          onToggleOpen={this.onToggleOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<GoogleMapsSample />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a question though - I haven't passed `isOpen={isOpen}` to the `MyMapComponent` and I added `this.onToggleOpen = this.onToggleOpen.bind(this);` to the constructor. Then when I clicked on the marker, I saw the `console.log` statement, also changing the value of `this.state.isOpen`, but the bubble above the marker is not appearing (`<InfoWindow>`). Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: Could you paste the whole code here or create a codesandbox so that I can help. Also, if the above answer is correct do you mind upvoting it?